# How to combine fade out animation with finishing an activity without using overridePendingTransition()?

Tags: android

I'm using startAnimation() on a layout object to fade in the appearance of an activity (which covers a portion of the screen). This works great when the activity is created, but when the activity finishes the animation doesn't have time to complete before the activity is dismissed.

Is there a way of starting an animation and then getting a callback when its finished so that I can dismiss the activity at that point?

The code is as follows:

```
....
private RelativeLayout      mLayout;
private Animation           mAnimationFadeIn;
private Animation           mAnimationFadeOut;
....

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     mAnimationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
     mAnimationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
    ....




    mLayout = (RelativeLayout) stub.findViewById(R.id.overlayBarLayout);
    mLayout.startAnimation(mAnimationFadeIn);
    ....
```

When dismissing the activity:

```
    if (mLayout != null)
        mLayout.startAnimation(mAnimationFadeOut);
    finish();
```

How can I perform the animation before the activity dismisses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Animation` has the possibility to set a delegate, `Animation.AnimationLister`, which in turn has three methods

1. `onAnimationStart`
2. `onAnimationRepeat`
3. `onAnimationEnd`

you can call `finish()`, when `onAnimationEnd` is invoked. To set it you can use [setAnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener))